# Remove Refresh Help Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the div recentactivity to only refresh when Remove is clicked

< a href='#' onclick=\"javascript:remove_wall('$id')\">Remove

but when every i click on the link it keeps trying to refresh.
when the mouse go's over the tr a link comes up saying remove here is the code for that.

```
$(function () {
    $("tr").hover(function () {
        var id = this.id.split('_').pop();
        $("#remove_" + id).show();
    }, function () {
        var id = this.id.split('_').pop();
        $("#remove_" + id).hide();
    });
});
```

Here is what happened when you click the link.

```
function remove_wall(id) {
    var refresh = setInterval(function () {
        $("#recent_activity").load("activity.php?random=" + unique_requestid());
    }, 1);

    $("#contentArea").load("remove.php?wall_id=" + id + "");
};
```

The remove in php is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using setInterval - which repeats a function every x milliseconds, where x is the interval given.

What you really need to use is setTimeout - which will start a timer and then run once the timer counts down, and will run only once.

Your code should look like this:

```
function remove_wall(id) {  
    var refresh = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#recent_activity").load("activity.php?random=" +unique_requestid());
    }, 1);
    $("#contentArea").load("remove.php?wall_id="+id+"");
};
```

Link for further reading: [Timers with setTimeout and setInterval](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)